# Redirect to /404/

Tags: redirect, 404-error, wp-redirect

Is there a way I can redirect the URL slug of the 404 template to /404/ so so for example if I have /category/media/blah it redirects to /404/

Is that possible I don't know if it can be done using .htaccess.

Ronny

Comment: A redirect is a 30x status code, a 404, as the number says, is a 404 code. :) The moment you redirect a request, it's not a 404 anymore.

Comment: Note there are big negative consequences to doing things this way. For example if google sees a page returns a `404` it'll update its index, but you want a redirect which is a `301`. On top of that, your page titled `/404` will return a `200` code, not a `404` code. Have you considered using the `404.php` template that WP automatically loads on 404's instead? You don't need a page template and a page to style 404 errors

Answer (score 0):

So you can do something like  this:

1. Open the `404.php` file and add these lines to the top of it. If you don't have one, create it. This will ensure WordPress uses this file for all permalinks that no longer exist or never existed.

```
    <?php 
    /**
    * Template Name: 404 Page
    */
    
    $four_oh_four = get_permalink( get_page_by_path( '404' ) );
    wp_redirect( $four_oh_four );
    exit();
```

2. Create a page with slug '404'.The above code will now redirect from the regular 404 template to a page with '404' slug.

I haven't tested it but should work.

Optionally, you could also use PHP's default redirection using headers if you want to. I just used WordPress' redirection API.

Comment: Do consider what @fuxia says above. You'll have problems with your SEO if you do what you desire but you have a solution to what you want.

Comment: Actually thinking about Im not going to change the url slug as its not needed

Comment: Yeah, in most cases, you won't need a redirect. Just utilize the 404.php in the best way possible. You can link to other posts on the 404 pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to your Homepage, try something like this in the 404.php:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".get_bloginfo('url'));
exit();
?>
```

You can modify this to redirect to someurl.com.